# WEBrick server losing constant settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I have recently changed my app to read a model's constants in from YAML files stored in Amazon S3 (set up in application.rb in an after_initialize). This works without a problem, except WEBrick seems to be losing the constants. It works fine when started, but after some time I'll refresh a view and it will report that the constant isn't initialized. There are no errors, and restarting the WEBrick server resolves the problem.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

> Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development ..
>
> INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>
> INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I can't provide specific answer to this, as I've never faced it. But how about considering to create a class which will contain the constants? Something like `class Constants CONSTANT1=..; CONSTANT2=..;... end`

Comment: @RubyRacer Thanks for the prompt response. At the moment I'm putting them into a ActiveRecord model class e.g. Person, and I'm setting the constant Person::SALUTATION_OPTIONS = YAML.load(..). I hadn't considered putting them into a separate class, as it means refactoring a significant amount of code. I haven't seen it going wrong in Production (Apache/Passenger), so I think it may be a WEBrick issue.

Comment: Yea, I thought it might be somehow so, but no harm dropping an extra idea. Sorry, I can't help :(